# How to prevent Redux dispatch from re-rendering the child components

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have the below component:

```
import * as React from "react";
import {useAppDispatch, useAppSelector} from "./store/hook";
import {fetchUser} from "./store/slices/user/auth-slice";
import {useDispatch} from "react-redux";

function App() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchUser());
    }, [])

    const [loading, error] = useAppSelector((state: any) => [
        state.auth.loading,
        state.auth.error,
    ])

  return (
      <>
            {loading ? (
              <div
                className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
                style={{ height: "100vh" }}
              >
                <CircularProgress color="inherit" />
              </div>
            ) : (
              <Layout>
                <Suspense fallback={<CircularProgress color="inherit" />}>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/regions/" replace />}/>
                        <Route path="ipam" element={<Ips />}/>
                    </Routes>
                </Suspense>
              </Layout>
            )}
            </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

store/slices/user/auth-slice:

```
import {createAsyncThunk, createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import UserModel from "models/userAction";
import axios from "api/axios-base";
import {getUserDetails} from "../../../api/services";
import {useAppDispatch} from "../../hook";

export const fetchUser = createAsyncThunk('auth/user', async () => {
    return getUserDetails().then((response) => {
        return response.data;
    }).catch(err => {
        return err;
    })
})


const initialState: UserModel = {
    user_id: null,
    email: '',
    name: '',
    isLoggedIn: false,
    loading: false,
    error: false,
}


const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'auth',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        Login(state: any, action: any) {
            state = {
                ...initialState,
                isLoggedIn: true
            }
            return state;
        }
    },
    extraReducers: builder => {
        builder
            .addCase(fetchUser.pending, (state, action) => {
                state = {
                    ...initialState,
                    loading: true
                }
                return state;
            })
            .addCase(fetchUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state = {
                    ...initialState,
                    ...action.payload.data,
                    isLoggedIn: true,
                    loading: false
                }
                return state;
            })
            .addCase(fetchUser.rejected, (state) => {
                state = {
                    ...initialState,
                    loading: false
                }
                return state;
            });
    }
});


export const authActions = authSlice.actions;
export default authSlice;
```

Now the issue is `Ips` which is a sub-component of App, renders twice:

```
function Ips() {
    useEffect(() => {
        alert('test')
    }, [])


    return (
                <div className={classes.Ip}>
                    test
                </div>
    );
}

export default Ips;
```

hence running the alert("test") twice, I found out the issue comes after this portion of code within my authSlice turns loading True then making it false, when I comemnt it, there is no re-rendering happening to take place inside  Child component.

```
builder
            .addCase(fetchUser.pending, (state, action) => {
                state = {
                    ...initialState,
                    loading: true
                }
                return state;
            })
```

How can I prevent such re-rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are re-rendering all app routes when calling that first `fetchUser` API. The child component `Ips` is not re-rendered, it is in fact **remounted**.

The simplest solution and IMO still correct (not a workaround): Initial value of `loading` should be `true`

```
const initialState: UserModel = {
    user_id: null,
    email: '',
    name: '',
    isLoggedIn: false,
    loading: true, // <--- `true` instead of `false`
    error: false,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of `useAppSelector` here rerenders your application a lot more than it would need:

```js
    const [loading, error] = useAppSelector((state: any) => [
        state.auth.loading,
        state.auth.error,
    ])
```

This selector creates a new array every time it is called. `useAppSelector` will execute your selector every time something is dispatched - and if the result is not equal (and here it is not referentially equal), it will rerender.

Call `useAppSelector` twice instead to keep both results stable unless they are actually changing in the store (and require a rerender):

```js
    const loading = useAppSelector(state => state.auth.loading)
    const error= useAppSelector(state => state.auth.error)
```

(if you have your `useAppSelector` typed correctly, you don't need to specify a type for `state`, it will be inferred automatically)

As for why your `useEffect` fires twice: in React 18 with StrictMode on, during Developement every `useEffect` will fire twice. That's how React works.

Comment: Appreciate your detailed explanation, I had  tried removing StrictMode before but didn't help me, in my case, the issue was loading which at first was false but then it became true which is a change making an unnecessary re-rendering, though I've been coding React for more than a year now, but still I can't find the solid way of coding the right way in React JS given the new Redux-Toolkit technology and the lack of articles about it, I would appreciate any solid boilerplates, resources etc, that can help me with real projects. Again thank you for your time.

Comment: Nothing has changed there between the old Redux and Redux-Toolkit. The React-Redux hooks are around since 2019, they work with RTK as they did with Redux and there have not been any changes in them. Also, RTK itself exists since 2019 - it is not exactly new either.
Generally, the official Redux template (`npx create-react-app my-app --template redux`) might be a good starting point, but things like you did here like actively unmounting components do not have anything with any of that. That's React.

Comment: You might also keep in mind that rendering a component twice is incredibly cheap and you are probably just overoptimizing something that never was a problem. Always measure first if something is actually a problem. A double render usually is not - 20 renders per second could be, but could just as well be totally okay. You'd need to use the React Profiler to find out.